# How to update system tray icon with TideSDK?

Tags: updates, system-tray, tidesdk, trayicon

On my index.html I've added a new system tray icon to the application (which works fine):

```
tray = Ti.UI.addTray("inactive_icon.png", function(evt){
    if (evt.getType() == 'clicked') {
      if (!current_window.isVisible()){
        current_window.show();
      }
    }
});
```

When the user follows a link on my index.html, he gets to an other site called active.html.
On this site the Icon should change from 'inactive_icon.png' to 'active_icon.png'. Unfortunately I can't transfer the tray Object to this site. So I have no access to that tray icon anymore.

How do I change the Icon?

I've tried to use :

```
TI.UI.clearTray();
```

and the than build a new tray icon for my application. But when I do this, the Icon changes but the command current_window.show(); seems to be broken.

So, whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hum so sorry I'm new in Stackoverflow. 
So take a look at this code :

```
Ti.UI.createMenuItem('Change Icon', function(e) {
        //Something's going on... let's change the icon.
        tray.setIcon('tray-active.png');
        setTimeout(function() {
            tray.setIcon('tray.png');
        }, 3000);
    }),
```

The author will change the icon in the systray. When the user click on the menu item called "ChangeItem", th icon is changed within 3 seconds (the settimeout).

You can check the complete code here : https://github.com/meeech/Menu-App